# how to add a line break in javascript that works with paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this function to format a certain string :

```
var desc = document.getElementById('desc');
            var parContent = desc.textContent.trim();
            var tempPar = "";
            var j = 0;
            var k = 0;
            var built_val = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < parContent.length ; i++)
            {
                if (j == 19 || i == parContent.length-1)
                {
                    tempPar = parContent.substring(k, i);
                    tempPar = tempPar.concat("- \n");
                    built_val = built_val.concat(tempPar);

                    tempPar = "";
                    //Restart j
                    j = 0;
                    //update k
                    k = i;
                    continue;
                }
                j++;
            }
            desc.textContent = built_val;
```

Desc is a dynamic paragraph that is usually empty at first then filled (its data are composed after the page loads), j is the number of characters desired in one line.

Though now I have another problem and that is \n doesn't work ; I also tried br 
 . How can I insert a new linebreak within a javascript string such as "built_val" ? please note how it's assigned to an Html

after everything.

Comment: `var built_val = 'foo' + '\n' + 'bar';`. a line break is a text char like any other. it just happens to have special meaning when it comes time to display that string in some environments. But since you're dealing with html, realize that html doesn't care about line breaks. it only cares about `<br>`.

Comment: @MarcB I do realize the difference between the two -linebreaks as chars & an Html tag-, though both don't work. Every 19 chars, the code inserts "<br/>" as it is without adding the actual break. It doesn't read it as a tag rather as another string.

Comment: @MohammedBaashar that's because you're setting it to the `textContent` property. Try `innerHTML`

Comment: Wait, why are you implementing text wrapping yourself instead of using CSS?

Comment: @yts thank you very much, that was the correct answer ; now the code works probably. For readers though, please replace "\n" with "<br/>

Comment: @SecondRikudo the original paragraph "desc" is governed by other css rules & also shared between many other pages in my code ; I kept its style fixed (colors, font...etc), but at some special pages it must mutate. I use the script only in some pages when it's required.

Comment: @MohammedBaashar you're welcome. If you feel that way, I'm a little confused by your actual correct answer choice :) Nothing against Rikudo..

Comment: @yts Rikudo's answer work with divs, which is another good approach : ) but accurately enough for my case, yours do fine ; Now it's chosen as  the answer ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textContent property sets the literal text of the element (by adding a text node), and will not parse your tags as html. Instead, you should do this:

`desc.innerHTML = built_val;`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're using `.textContent` which is why `<br>`s won't be parsed (which is a good thing!)

You want to use `document.createTextNode()` and `document.createElement('br')`.

```
var desc = document.getElementById('desc');
var parContent = desc.textContent.trim();
var tempPar = "";
var j = 0;
var k = 0;
var built_val = "";

for (var i = 0; i < parContent.length; i++) {
    if (j == 19) {
        tempPar = parContent.substring(k, i);
        tempPar = tempPar.concat("- \n");
        desc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tempPar));
        desc.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

        tempPar = "";
        //Restart j
        j = 0;
        //update k
        k = i;
        continue;
    }
    j++;
}
// No need for textContent anymore. Appending nodes did the work for us!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: an `Array.forEach` and `String.slice` method:

```js
var desc = document.querySelector('#desc');
var parContent = desc.textContent.trim();
var block = 0;
parContent.split('').forEach(
  function(v, i) {
    if (i % 19 == 0) {
      desc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(parContent.slice(block, i)));
      desc.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
      block = i;
    } 
  }
);
// last part
desc.appendChild(document.createTextNode(parContent.slice(block)));
```

```html
<p id="desc">
  This string should be truncated every 19th position right? 
  Ok, let's give it a try using [Array.forEach]<br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy regex version to wrap text as well:

```
function Wrap(src, maxLineLength) {
    return src.replace(new RegExp("(.{1,"+maxLineLength+"})", "g"), "$1<br/>\r\n");
}
```

Though this wraps on characters, not words.